# What are the benefits of using recommendation models over classification or regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I understand there are specialized models for recommendation such as Collaborative Filtering, Matrix Factorization, or Factorization Machine. But I think recommendation problems can be framed as classification or regression by transforming the data. What are the main advantages of using recommendation models as opposed to classification or regression models?

For example, let's say there is data about people matching or not matching.

[image]

We can transform data and create perfectly balanced data by taking matches, and for each match, randomly selecting a user from millions of users and marking it as not a match (very low probability to be a match). Then, we can train a binary classification model. We can incorporate implicit and explicit feedback as features. If we know enough info for new users, we will not have cold start problems either.

| Feature | Feature | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 feature | User2 feature | TRUE |
| User1 feature | User1234 feature | FALSE |

Can anyone please help me understand why Factorization Machine is preferred over gradient boosting classifier in the recommendation space, for example?

Comment: You have re-formatting the problem to a classification problem in a way that changes the task. Your model is now no longer recommending a match for a user. Rather, it is predicting if two users are a match. So to make a recommendation for a new user, you would have to repeatedly make predictions for combinations of the new user and an existing user until you found a match.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I understand that feeding all pairs into the model for inference can be expensive. Besides that, do you know what the main advantages are of framing this as a recommendation rather than a classification?